# How to set HTML table cell width using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a HTML table like the below;

```
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
<td style="width: 30px">cell</td>
<td class="cell">cell</td>
<td class="cell">cellcell</td>
<td class="cell">cellcellcell</td>
<td class="cell">cellcellcellcell</td>
<td class="cell">cellcellcellcellcell</td>
<td class="cell">cellcellcellcellcellcell</td>
<td style="width: 30px">cell</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table is designed to stretch to screen (or a div having specific width). I want equal width for all cells having `class="cell"` and this works well when the character length of text in all cells having `class="cell"` are equal. But, I want to fix the cell width even if the character lengths of contents in `class="cell"` are different.

Also you can see that the first and last cells have fixed width, in **pixels** and others cell widths are to be calculated on the basis of percentage .. I want equal width for all cells (except first and last with fixed width in pixels).

I think this can be done using Javascript with the help of jQuery, by calculating the table cell widths on document ready, and then adding some function using `on window resize` and thereby calculating cell widths. The cell widths will be `(tablewidth in px - 60px)/6` I am a beginner and I don't know much.. How can I do this using jQuery and (or) Javascript.

It will be very helpful if someone make me a fiddle..

Comment: 1. how can we set the width using css or html?
2. how can we do this using javascript/jquery?

Comment: You're saying you want every cell to be the same common width (that stretches) and then you're saying you want to fix the cell width.  Perhaps you can clarify your requirements.  Otherwise, it seems like you should simply set your individual `<td>` widths using percentages in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You could just do that with CSS, by applying each `td` an equal percentage:</strike>

```
td{
 width:   16%;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/wKmxD/

With your updated question, you could do it with javascript by first storing the widths into an array, and then referencing that on `window resize`, and use the aspect ratio difference to place new widths:

```
var w = [];
var tw = $('table').width();
$('table td').width(function(i,e){
    w[i]=e;
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    $('table td').width(function(i){
    return ($('table').width()/tw)*w[i];
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/543D9/

Comment: I was about to post almost verbatim the same answer.

Comment: Six columns at 16% each only adds up to 96%... I don't think the left-over 4% is going to be handled very well cross-browser... (it's really a contradiction since an object is equal to the sum of its parts).  Besides, I don't think he's asking for that, otherwise he could have just set his `<td>` widths in the HTML.  On the other hand, I'm not sure I even understand what he's asking.

Comment: @Niklas.. u have a good logic, but how if I have some tds with specific length in pixels??.. I have re-edited my question to avoid further confusions and you will know what I am trying to say... :)

Comment: @blasteralfred not working how? It is keeping the aspect ratios of the cells the same

Comment: hi @Niklas, hav a look @ the fiddle and my updated question :)

Comment: @blasteralfred how do you plan on keeping the same **aspect ratio** and identical width, if there isn't enough room for each cell with the minimum required width?

Comment: Hi @Niklas, I again updated the question... :) have a look... :) .. sorry, I am a beginner..